# I am trying to download virtualbox, but I get a failed message

Tags: virtualbox, downloads

Here is the fail message from vbox-install.log:
DKMS:

```
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

I guess I could also ask what is a kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel